# Calculate $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{3x-2y}{6x^2+y^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

So my task was to find domain,limit points of domain of function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ $$f(x,y)=\frac{3x-2y}{6x^2+y^2}$$

$\mathscr{D}_f= \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0) \}$

$\mathscr{D}_f^{'}= \mathbb{R}^2$

I think this is correct. Now I have to say if limit of $f$ exists in all limit points. My argument is that function is continuous on domain, so limit exists in all points of domain and it is equal to function value in that point. Now I have to check limit in $(0,0)$.

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{3x-2y}{6x^2+y^2}$$

It has form $\frac{0}{0}$ so I have to use tricks. I can't use derivatives because we haven't done it yet. I tried to apply array $(\frac1{n},\frac1{n})_n$ or $(\frac1{n},0)_n$, but I am getting $\infty$. Can somebody tell me what are tricks to calculate limit in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: You can also just approach by line $y=x$, it whole simplifies to $\frac{1}{7x}$ and you can immediately see the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You've already done the work you need to do.  If the limit exists, then it must exist and take the same value no matter what sequence you approach $(0,0)$ along.  So if you've found that along some sequence approaching $(0,0)$ the value of $f(x,y)$ approaches $\infty$, that means that the limit does not exist.

Comment: But did I do it correct? Can you apply this sequence? I don't know if I have done it correctly

Comment: Yes, you should be getting that it goes to $\infty$ for the sequences you mentioned.